# need to send golang data to html by button click

Tags: html, ajax, go

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    
)
type GetTime struct{
    Current_time string `json:"date"`
}
func main(){
  t:=(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    ctime:=GetTime{Current_time:t}
    byteArray,err:=json.Marshal(ctime)
    {
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(byteArray))
}
```

I need to send the above mentioned Go lang data to Html Form when the button is Clicked in Html Page

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, or state the problem you encountered while trying to implement your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably put very little effort into figuring this out. Though I am bored so I decided to help you out. Here is your backend:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Response struct {
    CurrentTime string
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web")))

    http.HandleFunc("/get-time", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctime := Response{
            CurrentTime: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339),
        }
        byteArray, err := json.Marshal(ctime)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        rw.Write(byteArray)
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And you also need frontend located in (web/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="gt">get time</button>
    <div id="res"></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("gt").onclick = async (e) => {
            var req = await fetch("\get-time").then(r => r.json())
            document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = req.CurrentTime
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm new to this language i need to learn more on this where can I learn it and please suggest me some site links for learning more on go

Comment: IF you want some starting lessons that can introduce you to golang and programming in general, I can give you couple lessons on it. Of course not everyone wants to spend money on learning process (I newer needed to do so). My advice is to set your self a goal. Good starting point with go is trying to make a website. Even if you don't finish it, its always a good experience and next time you do it, you will get lot further then the first time. Making website though does not involve only go so if you want pure go project you can make a game in it.